# Maven build process - Building two projects using one POM

Tags: maven

Initially I had only one project (MainProject) but now I want to add another sub project (Both are independent) and that resides inside my main project and it has it's own POM.

```
 MainProject
  +--- pom.xml
  +--- src
  +--- SubProject
          +--- pom.xml
          +--- src
```

Now I am looking for a way to building two projects using one build. I have gone through multi module project (http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-weather.html) but I do not want to alter the structure of current project by moving MainProject code to a sub directory. So how can I build both the project in one shot?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you don't want to move the MainProject code? Much of maven's power comes from how it encourages certain 'standard' practices. Understanding why you don't want to move the code may suggest a particular approach

Comment: Basically my subproject is a executable jar which is used for some initial setup. It just contain couple of classes but the main project is almost two years old. Since I have already integrated jenkins into the main project, I want to generate jar as part of the same build process. Since many developers are working on the main project, I really don't want to mess around with the current project structure. All this changes should go behind the scene.

Comment: The 'best' most supportable and practical way of doing this is to move the code. If your jenkins builds are set up correctly, you should not need to change them at all (I did exactly the same on a project recently). You will need to time your changes to minimise disruption to other developers - but it's no worse than a tricky merge conflict...

Comment: Hi Harry, Yes, I am able to do this. Just I wanted know if there is some other way to solve this issue. Thank you!  :)